# Trying to window.open and postmessage on same onclick version2

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, postmessage

Here is a much more simplified version of my previous question. I have a button that is supposed to open a page with an iFrame and also post a message to change the source of the iframe on that page.

Then I have a button that just opens the page, and one that just sends the message.

The Just Open and the Just Send buttons work perfectly (as long as you leave the window open for the Just Send one to have something to send to). However the Open and Send button does not work... and I do not know why. Thanks very much for any help.

The html:

```
    <button type="button" id="myBtn">Open and Send Message</button>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn1">Just Open</button>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn2">Just Send</button>
```

The javascript:

```
function openNumberIndex(){
         nIndex = window.open('numberindex.html');
    }
     
    function sendMessage(){
         let msg={nFrame: 'glossary-index.html#monad'};
         nIndex.postMessage(msg,"*")
         nIndex.focus();
    } 
    
    var nIndex; 
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn"); 
    var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");
    var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");
     
    btn.addEventListener("click", openNumberIndex);
    btn.addEventListener("click", sendMessage); 
    btn1.addEventListener("click", openNumberIndex); 
    btn2.addEventListener("click", sendMessage);
```

The issue (I am guessing) is with the presentation of the two event listeners for the var btn...

Comment: Don't create duplicates [Trying to window.open and postmessage on same onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74146335/trying-to-window-open-and-postmessage-on-same-onclick)

Comment: Sorry I don't know the etiquette... should I delete that one? This one is more direct.

Comment: you have to wait a moment for the window to open before it's methods are exposed. it need not be loaded, so a timeout should work, but might be better to use a loading event on the popup to trigger the next action.

Comment: @dandavis When you say a loading event on the popup - I guess I have no idea what that would look like. I get what you are saying that the postMessage is being sent before the popup can handle it, but not quite sure how the popup would hold onto that information while fully loading.

Comment: something like `nIndex.onload=sendMessage;` but fancier

Comment: ok I will try to learn about that - thanks very much! (This forum is extremely helpful for someone like me who is teaching themselves, I appreciate the tips).

Comment: @dandavis I just for the life of me cannot get this to work.... the timeout option works, but only occasionally... So - you offered a few options and I would rather not rely on a time out. 

With the nindex.onload=sendMeassage.... is that something I would put in the original open window function? 

And then for the other option - the onload on the recipient page... I tried doing a window.onload=function(){.....} wrapper around the mesage listener code I had, but that didn't seem to work either.